# Finding equilibrium points of a system of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system, sagemath, python

I am currently working on a spatially explicit ODE model with dispersion to study the population dynamics of mosquitoes. I wish to compute the equilibrium values of the populations as functions of the parameters in the model. The set of equations are presented below.
$$ 
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dE_p}{dt} =& \beta_p M_p - \dfrac{E_p}{d_{E_{p}}} - \mu^0_{E_{p}} \left( 1 + \dfrac{E_p + L_p}{K_p}\right) E_p, \\[5pt]
\dfrac{dL_p}{dt} =& \dfrac{E_p}{d_{E_{p}}} - \dfrac{L_p}{d_{L_{p}}} - \mu^0_{L_{p}} \left( 1 + \gamma \dfrac{E_p + L_p}{K_p}\right) L_p, \\[5pt]
\dfrac{dP_p}{dt} =& \dfrac{L_p}{d_{L_{p}}} - \dfrac{P_p}{d{_{P_{p}}}} - \mu_{P_{p}} P_p, \\[5pt]
\dfrac{dM_p}{dt} =& \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{P_p}{d{_{P_{p}}}} - \mu_{M_{p}} M_p + \sum_{i=1}^{\overline{p}} m_{ip} M_i - \sum_{i=1}^{\overline{p}} m_{pi} M_p\\
\end{align}
$$
I have equated the right hand sides to zero and tried to solve the system by susbstitution, but failed to do it. solve from Sagemath is also unable to help.

I will appreciate any help in finding a symbolic solution to this system of equations.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a Lotka-Volterra type system?

Comment: also have you already tried solving for the case p=1?

Comment: The system is kind of a Lokta-Volterra in the sense that, death rates for the larvae E and L are density dependent. However, there is no predation on any species by the other. As to solving for a single patch system, I tried but ended up with an intractable polynomial in the end. this led me ti the conclusion I might be doing something wrong and decided to ask for a different opinion here.